# capturing/replaying requests with python gives a different result than a browser

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to interact with the form at https://referti.policlinicodiliegro.it/servizi/#/portalereferto/ritiro via command-line / python.

I captured a request/response via Chrome Developer Tools network tab:

It shows:

REQUEST HEADERS:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryPvCnB4Ae6FtNAcnc
Referer: https://referti.policlinicodiliegro.it/servizi/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

REQUEST PAYLOAD:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryPvCnB4Ae6FtNAcnc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="serviceName"

PortaleRefertoPublicService
------WebKitFormBoundaryPvCnB4Ae6FtNAcnc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="methodName"

accessByPinSisWeb
------WebKitFormBoundaryPvCnB4Ae6FtNAcnc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parametri"

{"utente":"A","password":"B","pin":"C"}
------WebKitFormBoundaryPvCnB4Ae6FtNAcnc--
```

RESPONSE HEADERS:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, Content-Type, accept, MaxDataServiceVersion
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Cache-Control: no-store
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Language: en-GB
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 20 Apr 2023 16:55:07 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

RESPONSE PAYLOAD:

```json
{"message":"Credenziali non valide","errorCode":"","success":false}
```

(which is the expected result, since I input the invalid A/B/C credentials).

Then trying to replay the same request with python:

```py
import requests

r = requests.post('https://referti.policlinicodiliegro.it/IasiSmartControl/sisweb/dataServiceLoad.action', files={
    'serviceName': 'PortaleRefertoPublicService',
    'methodName': 'accessByPinSisWeb',
    'parametri': '{"utente":"A","password":"B","pin":"C"}',
}, headers={
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Referer': 'https://referti.policlinicodiliegro.it/servizi/',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
})


print(r.json())
```

I get this response:

```json
{'dataResult': ['<long alphanumeric code redacted>'], 'success': True}
```

where the long alphanumeric code is always the same...

Am I doing some mistake? Or is this website somehow detecting and preventing a non-web browser client? (How?)

I also try to inspect the sent request:

```py
for k, v in r.request.headers.items(): print(f'{k}: {v}')
print(r.request.body.decode('utf-8'))
```

and it looks as this:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://referti.policlinicodiliegro.it/servizi/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Content-Length: 463
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=c960d72f4d302329b731d85ef4ee4b37
--c960d72f4d302329b731d85ef4ee4b37
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="serviceName"; filename="serviceName"

PortaleRefertoPublicService
--c960d72f4d302329b731d85ef4ee4b37
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="methodName"; filename="methodName"

accessByPinSisWeb
--c960d72f4d302329b731d85ef4ee4b37
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parametri"; filename="parametri"

{"utente":"A","password":"B","pin":"C"}
--c960d72f4d302329b731d85ef4ee4b37--
```

which seems almost the same request as the one generated in the browser...

Comment: Before the request/response interaction you show, does the browser send a cookie to the website?

Comment: it seems not. but I see two requests to "dataServiceLoad.action", first of type "xhr" and second of type "fetch", both with response 200, and containing basically same information... however I'm a total newbie of these tools

Comment: @slothrop a cookie would be visible in the HTTP headers by the way, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but not necessarily the headers of *the same request*. If the exact same request produces different results in different contexts, then it's likely because of some state established between client and server *earlier in the session*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `files=` to `data=` then you can get the expected response, although it changes parameter encoding to `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```py
import requests


def log_in():
    r = requests.post(
        'https://referti.policlinicodiliegro.it/IasiSmartControl/sisweb/dataServiceLoad.action',
        data={
            'serviceName': 'PortaleRefertoPublicService',
            'methodName': 'accessByPinSisWeb',
            'parametri': '{"utente":"A","password":"B","pin":"C"}',
        },
        headers={
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Referer': 'https://referti.policlinicodiliegro.it/servizi/',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                          'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                          'Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        },
    )
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_in()
```

Output:

```
200
{"message":"Credenziali non valide","errorCode":"","success":false}
```

Comment: Oh, that's strange: the request sent by the browser was `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` so I looked up how to achieve that encoding with Python's `requests`, and it turned out `files=` had to be used instead of `data=`... anyways, thanks for finding a solution!